# Parse Domain in Text Input, replace from given list

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form hosted at following link:
http://laughtertab.com/url

The code for the form is as below:

What I need is when a person enters a URL from the website, It should replace the given domain from the input and replace with the chosen one from the list. I am new to coding and all I understood so far is I need to parse the URL into domain and path, but I can't make syntax on how to get it done, I will appreciate if I can get help on making it.

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title> Laughter Tab - UTM and OGP Propagated URL Builder </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body face='verdana'>

<br><br><br><br>
<center> 
 <div id="entries">
  <form name ="myform">
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <table style="table">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <right>
       Enter original URL without domain -
      </right>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="origin"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <right>
       Select OGP propagated domain -
      </right>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="radio" name="ogpd" value="http://www.laughters.xyz/"> laughtertab.com<br>    
      <input type="radio" name="ogpd" value="http://www.laughters.xyz/"> laughters.xyz<br>
      <input type="radio" name="ogpd" value="http://www.lolrising.rocks/"> lolrising.rocks<br>
      <input type="radio" name="ogpd" value="http://www.funspoted.net/"> funspoted.net<br>
      <input type="radio" name="ogpd" value="http://www.grumpy-kitten.com/"> grumpy-kitten.com<br>
      
     
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
     <td>
      <right>        
        Enter your GA Campaign name -
      </right>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="campaign"/><br>
     </td>
    <tr>
     <td>
     </td>
     <td><br>
      <right>
       <input type="button" value="Generate" onClick="collect(this.form)"/>
      </right>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
  </form>
  <br><br>
  <a href="http://www.laughtertab.com">Go Back to Laughter Tab Home Page</a>
 </div>




 <div id="results"> </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   

   function collect(frm) 
   { 
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+=""+frm.ogpd.value+""+frm.origin.value+"?utm_source=PNP&utm_medium=P1K&utm_campaign="+frm.campaign.value+"<hr>"
   frm.reset();
   } 
  </script>


<center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve? I'm not understanding what the goal is.

Comment: When somebody needs to share a link, they copy from the main website and put it here in the form.
laughtertab.com/url
Problem is the person who is sharing the link need to edit it manually and remove the domain from it and use the path to prepare a new shareable link.
See the following link builder for example:
www.viraldips.com/gpl

When somebody is going to prepare a URL for viraldips.com they simply copy it from the address bar and paste it in the form and by selecting new redirected domain their new shareable link gets ready. whereas in my case the sharer has to remove the domain manually.

Comment: a proper example:
a link copied from website: http://laughtertab.com/24-photos-proving-it-sucks-to-be-tall/

when shareable link is to be made, one need to separate the path like (24-photos-proving-it-sucks-to-be-tall/) and put in the form (at laughtertab.com/url) and then by clicking generate url they get a new domain's link.
What I want is while preparing new url, the user enter the full url (http://laughtertab.com/24-photos-proving-it-sucks-to-be-tall/) in the input and it's domain part should be replaced with new selected domain from the list.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly. You basically want to look for a domain name if it's in the input

```
frm.origin
```

and remove it from the value.

If that's the case then you can match a regex pattern, a generic example is:

```
/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/){0,1}([\w\d-]+\.)*([\w\d-]{1,63})(\.(\w{2,3}))\//i
```

Or you can google your own URL regex if you prefer

but anyways you just apply that to your value and replace it with "" (nothing)

```
frm.origin.value.replace(/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/){0,1}([\w\d-]+\.)*([\w\d-]{1,63})(\.(\w{2,3}))\//i, "");
```

Which gives you

```
function collect(frm) 
{ 
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+=""+frm.ogpd.value+""+frm.origin.value.replace(/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/){0,1}([\w\d-]+\.)*([\w\d-]{1,63})(\.(\w{2,3}))\//i, "")+"?utm_source=PNP&utm_medium=P1K&utm_campaign="+frm.campaign.value+"<hr>"
    frm.reset();
}
```

It's not a perfect solution but it should be a good starting point.